# Using range as argument returns a comparison

Tags: vimscript, functions, range

I am trying to capture the result returned from a function implementing `range` as an argument but apparently I get a comparison.

With the following code:

```
function! GetNumber() range
  return 4
endfunction

function! GetString() range
  return ""
endfunction

function! GetList() range
  echo a:firstline
  echo a:lastline
  return []
endfunction
```

After having selected some lines, I do the following operations:

- `echo '<,'>GetNumber()` or `let a = <,'>GetNumber()`: returns 0
- `echo '<,'>GetList()` or `let a = <,'>GetString()`: returns 1
- `echo '<,'>GetList()` or `let a = <,'>GetList()`:

  - `Error E691: Can only compare List with List`
  - `E15: Invalid expression: '<,'>GetList()`.

Yet, I can access to the variables `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` in the functions. I would like to know where could be my error and also where comes this comparison?

Does the same thing on Vim 7.4 and Vim 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the string to the result of the function: `echo '<,' > GetNumber()`.

`:echo` and `:let` accept an expression, where [the only way](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-function) to call a function is `funcname(args)`; you can't specify a range there. You could use `:call`, but [it discards the return value](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:call). Thus the only way to get something out of such a function is to set a global variable:

```
function! GetList() range
  echo a:firstline
  echo a:lastline
  let g:GetListResult = []
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the idea for bypassing this problem.